# jQuery removing errors generated on validation and stop repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery

still a little new to JS and a little stuck with some validation script i am writing. The errors repeat so need to remove if they exist and also then remove if they are valid.. any ideas?

```js
function validateEmail($email) {
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
return emailReg.test( $email );
  }
  
  function inputReset(element) {
if (element.hasClass('error')) {
  element.removeClass("error");
  element.siblings('.error-message').remove();
}
  }
  
  // Validation
  $('.validate-form').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var valid = true,
      message = '';

  $('form.validate input').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    inputReset($this); 
 
    if($this.prop('required')){
      
      // check for errors, if found lets get the messages for output
      if(!$this.val()) {
        $(this).addClass("error");
        var inputName = $this.attr('name');
        message = $this.data('error-message');
      }

      // validate the email input
      if($(this).hasClass('validate-email')) {
        var emailAddress = $this.val();
        if(!validateEmail(emailAddress)) { 
          $this.addClass("error");
          valid = false;
        }
      }

      $('.error-message[data-input-name="' + inputName + '"]').remove();
      // if not validated lets display the errors
      if(!valid) {
        //alert(message);
  $this.after('<div class="error-message" data-input-name="' + inputName + '">' + message + '</div>');
      }
      
    }

  });

if(valid) {
  $(".validate-form").submit();
}

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-right form-vertical">
      <form id="email_signup" class="klaviyo_bare_embed_twtw2v simpsons-form validate" action="//manage.kmail-lists.com/subscriptions/subscribe" data-ajax-submit="//manage.kmail-lists.com/ajax/subscriptions/subscribe" method="GET" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <input type="hidden" name="g" value="twtw2v">
        <input type="hidden" name="$fields" value="first_name,last_name" />
        
        <div class="klaviyo_messages">
          <div class="success_message">
            <p class="thank_you" style="display:none;">Thank's for signing up</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="klaviyo_field_group">
          <label for="k_id_first_name" class="kl_label">First Name:</label>
          <input type="text" value="" name="first_name" id="k_id_first_name" data-error-message="Error first name" placeholder="First Name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="klaviyo_field_group">
          <label for="k_id_last_name" class="kl_label">Last Name:</label>
          <input type="text" value="" name="last_name" id="k_id_last_name" data-error-message="Error last name" placeholder="Last Name" required />
        </div>
          <div class="klaviyo_field_group">
          <label for="k_id_email" class="kl_label">E-mail:</label>
          <input type="email" value="" name="email" id="k_id_email" class="validate-email" data-error-message="Error email" placeholder="E-mail" required />
        </div>
        <div class="klaviyo_form_actions">
          <button type="submit" class="btn klaviyo_submit_button validate-form">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would remove the else **valid = true;** parts of the code otherwise the form will submit if the last field checked is valid.

You probably just need a function to reset your inputs. Place this function outside of your click event then add **inputReset($this);** at the top of your each function

```
function inputReset(element) {
    if (element.hasClass('error')) {
        element.removeClass("error");
        element.siblings('.error-message').remove();
    }
}
```

Make sense? Hope it helps.

Comment: Ill give this a go, as its submitting one of the required fields still, give me a min.

Comment: Ive updated the demo, submit so get all errors, then enter an email and submit again but wrong error shows?

Comment: You still need valid = false; inside your first validation check **if(!$this.val())**

Comment: For some reason is it letting me submit with just entering the email, any ideas?

Comment: I updated the source with it back in i think... would you mind checking for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You may add the following lines at the start of your function:

```
$('.validate-form').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var valid = true,
  message = '';

  // Add this
  $(".error").removeClass(".error");
  $(".error-message").remove();

  ...
```

This will remove all the changes done in the DOM during the last execution of this method.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for me would be to add a data attribute to the error message, say, data-input-name and set it to the inputName variable, so each time you validate a field, you would first remove the error message and then add it again if the validation still fails like this:

(just the relevant part)

```
//removing error message, if it exists
$('.error-message[data-input-name="' + inputName + '"]').remove();

// if not validated lets display the errors


    if(!valid) {
        $this.after('<div class="error-message" data-input-name="' + inputName + '">' + message + '</div>');
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Done the trick, what would be the best way to remove the error message though.... its not replicating it when you submit a few times now but keeps the error there even with the input valid

Comment: Its cool, the removeClass and remove that the guy mentioned below helped as well. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding, you missing definition of `validateEmail()` function. The self-explanation of exception shows it **Uncaught ReferenceError: validateEmail is not defined**.

Comment: That's not their problem. They're lamenting the fact that the error message they're producing themselves keeps getting appended instead of getting replaced.